# label for radio won't make a new line

Tags: html, newline

I'm quite new to the HTML. I have to make a simple booking form. I'm getting stuck at the 'radio checking' label. After the "optgroup label" I need the radio option on a new line with a simple yes or no option after a text. Whatever I try it won't work and the yes or no option are right after the optgroup options.

```html
<label for="Aantal personen">Aantal personen</label>
<input id="Aantal personen" name="Aantal personen" type="number" min="1" max="10"><br>
<label for="Aankomstdatum">Aankomstdatum</label>
<input id="Aankomstdatum" name="Aankomstdatum" type="date"><br>
<label for="Verblijfsduur">Verblijfsduur</label>
<input type="range" name="weight" id="range_weight" step="2" min="2" max="20" oninput="range_weight_disp.value = range_weight.value">
 <output  id="range_weight_disp"></output><br>
<label for="Verzorging">Verzorging</label>
<select id="Verzorging" name="Verzorging">
<optgroup label="opties">
<option value="logies">Logies</option>
<option value="Logies met ontbijt">Logies met ontbijt</option>
<option value="Halfpension">Halfpension</option>
<option value="Volpension">Volpensension</option>
</optgroup>



<form id="radio">"Annuleringsverzekering"</label>
   <label for="annuleringsverzekering">     
   <label for="opt1"><input id="opt1" type="radio" name="mw" value="ja"  required>Ja</label>
   <label for="opt2"><input id="opt2" type="radio" name="mw" value="nee" required>Nee</label>  

 </form>
```

I hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong, thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, there are some problems with your code:

1. You're not closing the `<select>` tag.
2. You are closing the *annuleringsverzekering* `label` before you even open it.

Here's how you can fix it. Make sure that you also assign the `label` for *annuleringsverzekering* to an `id`.

```html
<label for="Aantal personen">Aantal personen</label>
<input id="Aantal personen" name="Aantal personen" type="number" min="1" max="10"><br>
<label for="Aankomstdatum">Aankomstdatum</label>
<input id="Aankomstdatum" name="Aankomstdatum" type="date"><br>
<label for="Verblijfsduur">Verblijfsduur</label>
<input type="range" name="weight" id="range_weight" step="2" min="2" max="20" oninput="range_weight_disp.value = range_weight.value">
<output id="range_weight_disp"></output><br>
<label for="Verzorging">Verzorging</label>
<select id="Verzorging" name="Verzorging">
  <optgroup label="opties">
    <option value="logies">Logies</option>
    <option value="Logies met ontbijt">Logies met ontbijt</option>
    <option value="Halfpension">Halfpension</option>
    <option value="Volpension">Volpensension</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>


<form id="radio"><label for="annuleringsverzekering">Annuleringsverzekering</label>
  <label for="opt1"><input id="opt1" type="radio" name="mw" value="ja"  required>Ja</label>
  <label for="opt2"><input id="opt2" type="radio" name="mw" value="nee" required>Nee</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I had not heard of the select tag before! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

you can add this CSS code to your form tag with radio Id:
display: block;

you can use this code to every element to have full line for it